# New project not showing on firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have recently had an issue with my firebase account where any new projects don't show in the CLI when I run `firebase init`.  I deleted a project I didn't need, and that updated immediately, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're certain there's a problem with the Firebase CLI, please contact support directly.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson I already submitted a ticket but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is a simpler solution, first, determine your `projectId` from the Firebase Console. Firebase usually adds a random number to your project's name i.e if you are using `demo` as the project name the projectId will look like `demo-1234`

Next, in your terminal, `cd` into your project's target directory and issue the followoing command

`firebase -P <projectId> init`

assuming `demo-1234` was my projectId, I will issue the command as below

`firebase -P demo-1234 init`

Comment: This worked for me. when I used ```firebase init``` without the project name, it'd tell me to add project first. When I tried to use ```firebase use --add <project-id>``` it'd tell me to init the folder first. Finally, this person's solution worked for me.

Comment: In the last step it only worked when I used "Don't Setup a default project" option.

Answer (score 20):

Use `firebase use --add projectId`, this will add your project

Answer (score 9):

I did

```
firebase logout
```

then

```
firebase login
```

It works for me

Comment: Yep, sometimes you just don't have a valid token (this was my case)

Comment: I simply needed to `firebase login` again. No logout necessary.

Comment: this worked for me. Any attempt to firebase -P xxx init or firebase use --add xxx failed. Logging out and back in updated the list of existing projects suggested by firebase init. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yea this is a weird one.

Use the `[don't setup a default project]` option

then, as mentioned by @Dragon, use `firebase use --add projectId` to add the project

Answer (score 2):

Check with `firebase login`.

You will get redirected to browser and just do sign in.

then `firebase -P <Project-ID> init`
Then follow all options that come along.

"Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder?" Choose "Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites."

"Select a default Firebase project for this directory:" Choose the project you created on the Firebase website.

"What do you want to use as your public directory?" Enter "build".

Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?" Enter "Yes".

"File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite?" Enter "No".

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to do when initializing is by using the --project option:

`firebase init --project <projectId>`

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me.

1. Get the Project Id from firebase console. e.g. myproject-2233
2. On Firebase CLI run below command
   $ firebase -P myproject-2233
3. Next Select the features you want to add e.g. Web Hosting
4. Next Select "Don't Setup a default project"
5. Give the public folder name

It worked only after choosing "Don't Setup a default project"

##

Answer (score 0):

For me, turns out I was logged into the Firebase CLI using a different account from the one that created the project. The solution was either to log into the CLI with the account that created the project with:

`firebase login`

or, using the Firebase console, invite the user who's logged into the CLI

Answer (score 0):

Just do a refresh in your firebase console, sometimes the firebase auth token is expired. I had the same issue and after refreshing it fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mac and npm

1. add on terminal: sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
2. firebase login (check your login console accounts are same)

   firebase projects:list (list all your firebase project)
3. cd to your project (go to your project folder and right click then
   go to
   new terminal at folder on this terminal write pwd
   you can get the path of the folder after
   that close the terminal )
4. type on at root folder terminal:  dart pub global activate
   flutterfire_cli
5. write on terminal : export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
6. write on terminal: firebase -P #copyYourProjectId# init
7. write on terminal:  firebase logout
8. write on terminal:  firebase login
9. write on terminal:  dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

   write on terminal:   use --add #copyYourProjectId# (now using the project)
10. write on terminal:  flutterfire configure
    project=#pasteyourprojectid#

{#select ios android web or macos }